# Filling null values with last not null one => huge number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I want to copy rows from SOURCE_TABLE to TARGET_TABLE while filling null values with last not null one.

What I have :

```
SOURCE_TABLE :
       A |    B |    C | PARENT | SEQ_NUMBER
       1 |    2 | NULL |      1 |          1
    NULL | NULL |    1 |      1 |          2
    NULL |    3 |    2 |      1 |          3

DEST_TABLE is empty
```

What I want :

```
DEST_TABLE :
       A |    B |    C | PARENT | SEQ_NUMBER
       1 |    2 | NULL |      1 |          1
       1 |    2 |    1 |      1 |          2
       1 |    3 |    2 |      1 |          3
```

To achieve that I'm dynamically generating the following SQL :

```
insert into TARGET_TABLE (A, B, C)  
select  coalesce(A, lag(A ignore nulls) over (partition by parent order by seq_number)) as A,  
        coalesce(B, lag(B ignore nulls) over (partition by parent order by seq_number)) as B,  
        coalesce(C, lag(C ignore nulls) over (partition by parent order by seq_number)) as C,  
from SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Everything works fine if SOURCE and TARGET tables have a small number of columns. In my case they have 400+ columns (yes this is bad but it is legacy and cannot be changed) and I got the following error :

> ORA-01467: sort key too long

- First I don't really understand this error. Is this because I'm using too many lag functions that use themselves "order by"/"partition by" ? Replace coalesce(A, lag(A....)) by coalesce(A,A) and the error disappear.
- Then, is there a workaround or another way to achieve the same result ?

Thx

Comment: possible workaround: create two or more destination tables, each with seq_number and a subset of the remaining columns, fill them the way you have figured out, and join them finally.

Comment: Can you copy the content and execute an update afterwards to replace the `NULL` values?

Comment: ammoQ : inserting the first 50 columns, then the 50 next ... works well indeed. I'm just concerned about performances. Plus, I don't know how to calculate the maximum number of column that will not lead to the "sort key too long" error. I seems it depends on the content of the columns and not only on the number of columns ! In one of my case it works up until 213 columns ??!!

Comment: Peter : I already tried this solution but the same error occurs :(

Answer (score 0):

just do it using pl/sql anonymous block:

```
declare
   x tgt_table%rowtype; --keep values from last row
begin
   for r in (select * from src_table order by seq_number) loop
       x.a := nvl(r.a, x.a);
       ...
       x.z := nvl(r.z, x.z);
       insert into tgt_table
       values x;
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Is this ok in term of performances ? Also my table is a parameter, meaning the code has to be able to handle different table dynamically.

Comment: @Olivier You can generate the pl/sql block dynamically (based on table definition) and execute it using execute immediate.  You can further improve the performance using forall.

Comment: Tried this solution and it works very well. I really thought that doing mass queries was much more faster than handling things line by line. But in this case it is the opposite. Thanks.